# Schedule legacy applications as single instance on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

A lot of legacy applications are deployed as containers. Most of them only need a few changes to work in a container but many of them are not built to scale, for example because they maintain session data or write to a volume (concurrency issues).

I was wondering if those applications are intended to run on Kubernetes and if so what is a good way to do so. Pods are not durable, so the desired way to start an application is by using a replication controller and setting replicas to 1. The RC ensures that the right amount of pods are running. The documentation also specifies that it kills pods if there are too many. I was wondering if that's ever the case (if a pod is not started manually).

I guess a database like Postgres (with an external data volume) is a good example. I have seen tutorials deploying those using a replication controller.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Replication Controller with 1 replica is indeed a good approach, it's more reliable than starting a single pod since you **benefit from the auto-healing mechanism**: in case the node your app is running on dies, your pod will be terminated an restarted somewhere else.

---

Data persistence in the context of a cluster management system like Kubernetes means that your data should be available **outside the cluster itself** (separate storage). I personally use EC2 EBS since our app runs in AWS, but Kubernetes supports a lot of other [*volume*](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/volumes.md) types. If your pod runs on *node A*, the volumes it uses will be mounted locally and inside your pod containers. Now if your pod is destroyed and restarted on *node B* this volume will be unmounted from *node A* and mounted on *node B* before the containers of your pod are recreated. Pretty neat.

Take a look at [persistent volumes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes), this should be particularly interesting for you.

Comment: I'm aware of how volumes work but some applications are not built to share volumes with other instances. To ask a more precise question: Is there a mechanism to ensure that there is always only exactly one instance running (not more)(similar to a setup w/o k8s).

Comment: That's what I was trying to explain in the first part of my answer. You can run only 1 replica of the same application by configuring your replication controller accordingly. In this case the storage (volume) associated to your pod definition will be used by a single app.